# awk loop over all fields in one file

Tags: sorting, csv, for-loop, awk, uniq

This statement gives me the count of unique values in column 1:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1}' infile1.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > outfile1.csv
```

It does what I expected (gives the count (left) of unique values (right) in the column):

```
117 5
 58 0
 18 4
 14 3
 11 1
  9 2
```

However, now I want to create a loop, so it will go through all columns.
I tried:

```
for i in {1..10} 
 do 
   awk -F ',' '{print $$i}' infile.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > outfile$i.csv
done
```

This does not do the job (it does produce a file but with much more data). I think that a variable in a print statement, as I tried with print $$i, is not something that works in general, since I did not come across it so far.

I also tried this:

```
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) infile.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr}' > outfile$i.csv
```

But this does not give any result at all (meaning syntax errors for infile and `sort` command). I am sure I am using the for statement the wrong way.

Ideally, I would like the code to find the count of unique values for each column and print them all in the same output file. However, I am already very happy with a well functioning loop.

Please let me know if this explanation is not good enough, I will do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through the columns and perform the same command in each one of them. So what you are doing is fine: pass the column name to `awk`. However, you need to pass the value differently, so that it is an `awk` variable:

```
for i in {1..10} 
 do 
   awk -F ',' -v col=$i '{print $col}' infile.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > outfile$i.csv
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Just do it in one awk command, something like this using GNU awk for 2D arrays and sorted `in` (untested since you didn't provide any sample input):

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" }
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) cnt[i][$i]++ }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        for (val in cnt[i])
            print val, cnt[i][val] > ("outfile" i ".csv")
}
' infile.csv
```

No need for half a dozen different commands, pipes, etc.